# Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 Pulse Secure VPN Unresponsive via command line

Tags: debian, vpn

I've a fully working vpn connecting via Windows.

Now I need to access it via an alternative server which has a no gui distro of Debian.

After the installation I've tried a command line approach but I literally got nothing:

```
root@itaxxxc666:/usr/local/pulse# /usr/local/pulse/PulseClient_x86_64.sh -h webvpn.interserv.com  -u mycomp\\USER -p PASSWORD -U https://webvpn.interserv.com/dana-na/auth/url_47/welcome.cgi -r interserv
```

Checking for missing dependency packages for command line client ...
executing command :

```
/usr/local/pulse/pulsesvc -h webvpn.interserv.com -u mycomp\USER -p PASSWORD -U https://webvpn.interserv.com/dana-na/auth/url_00/welcome.cgi -r interserv

root@itaxxxc666:/usr/local/pulse#
```

Tried also old path (no dana...) and also tried adding log level arg but nothing changes...

Any hint?

Support from Pulse is very lacky...just don't know how to gain access prom linux via this terrible vpn...

Comment: Can you get `pulseUi` to work? (It doesn't matter if the computer is headless, use `ssh -X` to log into it and run the remote GUI application with a local display.) If you can, see what command line it uses for `pulsesvc`. Is `pulsesvc` setuid root?

Comment: Hi this is interesting. I've managed to obtain xming and tried a sample app run like xclock with success. When I try to render a pulse client in my window desktop with "./pulsesvc" it hangs.

Comment: Hey...did managed to start via pulseUi. Now problem's changed! Need tls certificate!seems it can be solved via some research!

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' if you answer this I would accept. Pls note I've opened another issue:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551977/debian-gnu-linux-9-5-pulse-secure-vpn-ui-host-checker-stuck